# Ansible error with_together and user management

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, ansible

Having some annoying issue that I just cannot figure out.

Here is my code. If I completely comment out the group and groups variables everything works fine. But this as is spits out the errors below.

It basically tells me 
That group does not exist. In this example it says msg: "Group" 'all' does not exist. I have no idea what I need to do to fix this issue.

```
 - name: Add new group if it doesn't exist already
   group:
    name: "{{ group }}"
   when: group is defined

 - name: Add multiple users
   user:
    name: "{{ item.0 }}"
    comment: "{{item.1 }}"
    uid: "{{ item.2 }}"
    group: "{{ group }}"
    groups: "{{ groups }}"
    append: yes

   with_together:
     - "{{ name }}"
     - "{{ comment }}"
     - "{{ uid }}"
     - "{{ group }}"
And variable file:
name:
 - test1
 - test2

comment:
 - "comment1"
 - "comment2"

uid:
 - 150
 - 151

group: sudo

groups:
 - admin
 - test



However, now I am receiving this error.


failed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[u'test1', u'comment1', 150, u'sudo']) => {"failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"append": true, "comment": "comment1", "createhome": true, "expires": null, "force": false, "generate_ssh_key": null, "group": "sudo", "groups": "{'ungrouped': ['127.0.0.1'], 'all': ['127.0.0.1']}", "home": null, "login_class": null, "move_home": false, "name": "test1", "non_unique": false, "password": null, "remove": false, "shell": null, "skeleton": null, "ssh_key_bits": "2048", "ssh_key_comment": "ansible-generated on ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01", "ssh_key_file": null, "ssh_key_passphrase": null, "ssh_key_type": "rsa", "state": "present", "system": false, "uid": "150", "update_password": "always"}, "module_name": "user"}, "item": ["test1", "comment1", 150, "sudo"], "msg": "Group  'all': ['127.0.0.1']} does not exist"}
failed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=[u'test2', u'comment2', 151, None]) => {"failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"append": true, "comment": "comment2", "createhome": true, "expires": null, "force": false, "generate_ssh_key": null, "group": "sudo", "groups": "{'ungrouped': ['127.0.0.1'], 'all': ['127.0.0.1']}", "home": null, "login_class": null, "move_home": false, "name": "test2", "non_unique": false, "password": null, "remove": false, "shell": null, "skeleton": null, "ssh_key_bits": "2048", "ssh_key_comment": "ansible-generated on ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01", "ssh_key_file": null, "ssh_key_passphrase": null, "ssh_key_type": "rsa", "state": "present", "system": false, "uid": "151", "update_password": "always"}, "module_name": "user"}, "item": ["test2", "comment2", 151, null], "msg": "Group  'all': ['127.0.0.1']} does not exist"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is conflicting variable names. `groups` is a reserved variable and holds the groups from the inventory. And `all` is a automatically generated group which holds all the hosts of your inventory.

[From the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts):

> Even if you didn’t define them yourself, Ansible provides a few variables for you automatically. The most important of these are `hostvars`, `group_names`, and `groups`. Users should not use these names themselves as they are reserved. `environment` is also reserved.

and

> `groups` is a list of all the groups (and hosts) in the inventory. This can be used to enumerate all hosts within a group.

Simply rename your variable and it should work. In general it's a good idea to prefix all variables of a role with the role name. This gets more important if you use 3rd party roles, e.g. from Ansible Galaxy, just to avoid conflicts. So instead of `groups` you could use `myrole_groups` and can be quite sure there never will be conflicts.